# Resizing Colorbox Not Working!

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I loaded a colorbox modal with contents from another page of the website (AJAX example on the official demo). This page has a `Show more` button that when clicked, causes more contents to be shown. I also added additional code to attempt to resize the modal to show all of the content.

**CODE:**

```
$("#button_writereview").colorbox.resize();

$("#button_writereview").colorbox.resize({innerWidth:560, innerHeight:750});

$("#button_writereview").colorbox.resize({Width:560, Height:750});

$.colorbox.resize();

$.colorbox.resize({innerWidth:560, innerHeight:750});

$(this).colorbox.resize(); 

$.fn.colorbox.resize();

$('#button_writereview').css('height',500);
```

None of the above codes do anything except throw an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'resize' of undefined`

I just cant seem to figure out the resize!! I'm guessing its a problem calling the parent page from a click event in the modal.

Comment: Do you have another JS framework on your site?

Comment: have you included the colorbox `js`? your answer maybe duh! yeah but sometimes such things happen also make sure you have included the colorbox `js` after the jquery

Comment: Yup i included the colorbox js, and after jquery. Same problem with and without colorbox js loaded in the html file that is loaded into the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. there may be a jquery conflict as everybody is in love with the `$` anyway you can use    jQuery noConflict like

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src"/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript"> 
           jq = jQuery.noConflict(true); 
    </script>
   ```

now use `jq` instead of `$`

3. wrap your code inside

   $(function(){

   });
4. make sure both jquery.js and colorbox.js are loaded, sometimes they are included in the page header but didnt get loaded ...